# Service Account not able to attach project to shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to create a service project and attach an existing shared VPC in the host project to it.

When using my IAM credentials, I can perform this action. Here are permissions on the folder:

- Project Billing Manager
- Compute Shared VPC Admin
- Owner
- Folder Admin
- Folder Editor
- Project Creator
- Project Deleter

Here are the permissions the service account has on the folder which contains both the host and the service project.

- Project Billing Manager
- Compute Admin
- Compute Network Admin
- Compute Shared VPC Admin
- Kubernetes Engine Admin
- Security Admin
- Service Account User
- Owner
- Folder Admin
- Project Creator
- Project Deleter
- Project IAM Admin

No clue why I am getting the following error when I try to perform the action using the service account.

```
module.svc_project.module.project_factory.module.project-factory.google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project.shared_vpc_attachment[0]: Creating...

Error: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.organizations.enableXpnResource' permission for 'projects/host-project-a1b2c3'
More details:
Reason: forbidden, Message: Required 'compute.organizations.enableXpnResource' permission for 'projects/host-project-a1b2c3'
Reason: forbidden, Message: Required 'compute.organizations.enableXpnResource' permission for 'projects/svc-prj1-n1p2'


  on .terraform/modules/svc_project.project_factory/modules/core_project_factory/main.tf line 103, in resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" "shared_vpc_attachment":
 103: resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" "shared_vpc_attachment" {
```

**Environment**

- Terraform: 0.14.6
- project_factory module: "terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google" (version 10.1.1)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the role `roles/compute.xpnAdmin` at the Organization level and not at the folder or project level.

Comment: The use of the “Shared VPC Admin” role on folder level is currently in beta, when using the API or gcloud to do creations on the shared VPCs you will need to use ‘gcloud beta’ or the beta API, otherwise you get a permissions error [1].

Shared VPC [2] is currently in beta,if any changes have been done on Terraform that may affect its interaction with permissions for Shared VPC.

[1]
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#nominating_shared_vpc_admins_for_the_organization
[2] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#iam_in_shared_vpc

Comment: Turns out just having a folder level permission is enough after all.

Comment: Thanks @KameliaY. Was facing this issue with Terraform and added the provider google-beta for resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_service_project" "service-project" and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the [project_factory](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google/latest) module version to `10.3.2` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Terraform google provider doesn't support Shared VPC Admin, so Terraform will use the google-beta provider when using the creating or updating shared VPCs.

If you add the google-beta provider bit to your terraform, it should work:

```
provider "google-beta" {
    region      = $REGION
    zone        = $ZONE
}
```